# Go to file keyboard shortcut for espresso

Tags: html, editor, macrabbit-espresso

Does espresso have a keyboard shortcut to go to a file?

Such as <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> in TextMate, or control+ , in Visual Studio?

Comment: I've never heard of Espresso, but if Command+O doesn't work that's a little strange.

Comment: I edited the question for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't directly equivalent, but `control Q` (File->Show Quick Filter) will allow you to filter the files in PROJECT FILES based on filename.